# How can I find my public IP using the terminal?

Tags: networking

I am on DHCP, having dynamic IP.

Finding your public IP when using a GUI and a browser is extremely easy.
Simply go to Google.com and search for *"What is my IP"*. Google will display it in the very first line.

However I am unable to find my public IP when inside Ubuntu server.

I have created a system with Ubuntu server (LAMP Stack) for my personal use. This system boots up simply in terminal mode. I want to do SSH using some other system across the internet; thus knowing the public IP becomes necessary.

What is the command to display the current public IP adress of that system?