# How do I screenshare over the internet using Remmina Desktop client?

Tags: remmina

I want to screenshare my desktop with my cousin who lives out of town. What do I enter in the IP box to connect to his specific computer? The traditional 192.168.X.XXX won't work of course..I'm assuming I'll have to use his ISP IP with some type of string command to address his specific laptop..?

Answer (score 1):

The IP address to connect you to a remote desktop is the adress given to this remote computer by their Internet Servie Provider. You will have to find out this address from the remote computer (e.g. by opening an Internet browser there an go to [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com/)):

- [How can I find my public IP using the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145012/how-to-find-external-ip)

In case you need a frequent access to this computer you may also want to consider setting up a dynamic DNS service:

- see [Ubuntu help wiki: Dynamic DNS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS)

Comment: Multiple local computers can be connected to a Public IP address. How does it locate the specific one? The answer does not seem complete.