# How to get remote server's ip?

Tags: server, ssh, remote, ip

I've got the server's adress and I don't know how to get its ip adress. I have an access via ssh and I need it so bad, please help. (As for your information I've been looking for this for some time, seriously :/ )

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145012/how-can-i-find-my-public-ip-using-the-terminal/145169

Comment: How do you connect to it with ssh if you don't know it's ip? If you use a domain name, then you can run `nslookup` on the domain, or even `ping`.

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

It is a web service that returns originating IP address. Other information is also available, including

```
curl ifconfig.me/host # hostname
curl ifconfig.me/ua # user agent
curl ifconfig.me/forwarded # proxy settings
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know Remote system IP range then we can find it easily with nmap.

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV 10.0.0.0/24 > sshservers
```

So Here I am assuming my Remote host IP range ( 0 - 24) is **10.0.0.0/24** & as all of we know that SSH access will be done on Port 22 always.

hope that helps.